# What are these values starting with "0x"?

Tags: python, hex

I'm a student and I like to explore random Python files in my system. This helps me to learn a lot of stuff.

I encountered this code:

```
F32 = 0xFFFFFFFF                                                                  
                                                                                  
_k = [0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,                             
      ...                                                                         
     ]
```

I didn't understand what `0x` means.

I tried to find out what it is by typing

```
print(type(F32))
```

This shows `int`. But I have never seen this before.

Is this written in hex?

What is it's actual int value?

Comment: "This show me an int. But doesn't look like." - it's an `int`. "Is this written in hex?" - yes. "What is it's actual int value?" - 0xFFFFFFFF = 4294967295 (type `0xFFFFFFFF` into your Python interpreter and it will tell you this).

Comment: Sir, this means we can initialise our variable either by 4294967925 or by 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of answer you are expecting? You *already* checked the type – we cannot tell you more than what Python already did. You *already* have the value – we cannot tell you more than what you can ``print``. You *already* know about hex – what more do you expect?

Comment: I'm Sorry for wrong title. But sir, if both are same then, why the person who write this code do this. I mean he/she can actually write it in integer.

Comment: Does this is an efficient way to store value. Or to make the code unreadable?

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF is a special value because in the binary representation (like the number is stored in the memory of the computer) it means that all 32 bits are 1. This is more obvious when written like this than with the decimal representation. It's like writing the decimal number 999 is more clear than writing the hexadecimal number 0x3E7 (which is the same number).

Comment: @RajeevChauhan, hope my answer helped you to know what is this. If so mark this as correct

Answer (score 2):

Those strange things are `ints` written in hexadecimal format

```
F32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
print(F32)
print(type(F32))
```

Output:

```
4294967295
<class 'int'>
```